# Like tweets in twitter but throttled using timeout

Tags: javascript, twitter, console, settimeout, google-developers-console

This is the code I made to like tweets

I am trying to make the code to like tweets but I need a set timeout thing so that i don't get banned while using

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
for(var j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
for (const d of document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid="like"]')) {
    d.scrollIntoView(true);
    d.click()
  }};
```

I am trying to make a timeout but i don't know how to

I have tried to make it like this but it did not work

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
for(var j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
for (const d of document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid="like"]')) {
    d.scrollIntoView(true);
    await sleep({ seconds: 1 });
    d.click()
  }}; 

  const sleep = ({ seconds }) =>
    new Promise((proceed) => {
      console.log(`WAITING FOR ${seconds} SECONDS...`);
      setTimeout(proceed, seconds * 1);
    });
```

Comment: Why the loop? `for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
for(var j = 1; j < 9; j++) {` You are not using i or j anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in a loop.

From your comments it sounds like you want a bookmarklet

```js
javascript:(function() { const likes = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid=like]'); let cnt = 0; const clickLike = () => { if (cnt >= likes.length) return; const like = likes[cnt]; like.scrollIntoView(true); like.click(); cnt++; setTimeout(clickLike, 1000); }; clickLike(); })()
```

**Example in a page**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // page is ready
  const likes = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid=like]');
  let cnt = 0;
  const clickLike = () => {
    if (cnt >= likes.length) return; // stop
    const like = likes[cnt];
    like.classList.add("clicked"); // for show
    like.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    like.click();
    cnt++;
    setTimeout(clickLike, 1000); // wait a second
  };
  clickLike(); // start
});
```

```css
div[data-testid=like] {
  height: 100px
}
div[data-testid=like].clicked { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<div data-testid="like">Like 1</div>
<div data-testid="like">Like 2</div>
<div data-testid="like">Like 3</div>
<div data-testid="like">Like 4</div>
<div data-testid="like">Like 5</div>
```

Comment: I have just tried it but i get this
```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollIntoView')
    at clickLike (<anonymous>:6:8)```

Comment: I just tried to run it in Console(google) i get this `undefined`

Comment: How to run this script? Please explain, i am a little confused

Comment: Hi, I saw you just updated the answer but i get this now `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`

Comment: One }) too many - fixed

Comment: One last thing, why when i run the script it likes only 3 tweets, i want it to like 1 then wait 1 second then like 1, until 100 tweets, how to do that :P

Comment: If there are only 3 tweets on the page when you click and then loads more then the script perhaps needs something else.

Comment: does it neep looping or something?

Comment: You have not posted enough information for me to know